# Error while installing packages with ceph-common on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, software-installation, ceph

```
qwerty@hello:~$ sudo apt install vim
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
vim is already the newest version (2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 3203 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up ceph-common (15.2.11-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Setting system user ceph properties..usermod: no changes
..done
chown: cannot access '/var/log/ceph': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package ceph-common (--configure):
 installed ceph-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ceph-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: The error is from the `ceph-common` package. It clearly says "vim is already the newest version (2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5)."

Comment: But i want to deal with Error which is in bottom {E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)}

Comment: @muru's point is that you seem to have not read (or perhaps understood) your own output. You are asking a question about Package A, but your output clearly indicates the problem is with Package B. You have included no troubleshooting information about `ceph-common`: No attempt to reinstall or remove, no attempt to create the missing ceph logfile. Lots of troubleshooting clues and suggestions in that output.